# Как написать "безопасный" метод для сохранения файла?

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

Есть следующий код:

```
public AttachedFile SaveAttachment(NewAttachment attachment)
{
    var tmpFile = Path.GetTempFileName();

    try
    {
        using (var f = File.Open(tmpFile, FileMode.Append))
        {
            attachment.Stream.CopyTo(f);
        }

        string filePath = string.Empty;
        string dst = string.Empty;

        do
        {
            filePath = generatePathForAttachment();
            dst = Path.Combine(archiveDirectory, filePath);
        } while (File.Exists(Path.Combine(archiveDirectory, filePath)));                
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(dst));

        var attachedFile = new AttachedFile
        {
            OriginalTitle = attachment.OriginalTitle,
            Path = filePath,
            Size = attachment.Stream.Length,
            AuthorId = attachment.AuthorId,
            Created = DateTime.Now
        };

        File.Move(tmpFile, dst);

        _context.Set<AttachedFile>().Add(attachedFile);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return attachedFile;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

его назначение сохранение файла на сервере, код рабочий.

Помогите модифицировать данный код что бы свести последствия возникающих `Exception` к минимуму, т.е. мне необходимо что бы выполнилось либо все либо ничего.

Моей фантазии хватило только на оборачивании каждого *проблемного участка* в `try`, т.е. что то типа:

```
try
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(dst)))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(dst));
}
catch(Exception)
{
    //обработка исключения
}

try
{
    if (File.Exists(dst))
        File.Move(dst, src);
}
catch(Exception)
{
    //обработка исключения
}
```

ну и т.д., но я не уверен в правильности подхода. Был бы премного благодарен за советы.

---

Реализация метода генерации пути для файла

```
private string generatePathForAttachment(params string[] args)
{
    var dstPath = string.Empty;
    var srcString = string.Empty;
    if(args.Length==0)
    {
        srcString = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        srcString = string.Concat(args.Select(x=>x));
    }            
    var hash = getHashString(srcString);
    dstPath = Path.Combine(hash.Substring(0, 2), hash.Substring(2, 2), hash.Substring(4));
    return dstPath;
}

private string getHashString(string s)
{
    string hash = string.Empty;
    //переводим строку в байт-массим  
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s);
    //создаем объект для получения средст шифрования  
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider CSP =
        new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

    //вычисляем хеш-представление в байтах  
    byte[] byteHash = CSP.ComputeHash(bytes);            

    //формируем одну цельную строку из массива  
    foreach (byte b in byteHash)
        hash += string.Format("{0:x2}", b);

    return hash;
}
```

---

Фактически сервером выступает виртуальная машина, доступ к каталогу по мимо программы есть только у меня(как у разработчика) и администратор(но он туда не ходит)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42482/discussion-on-question-by-bald-------).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что требуется от кода? Я так понимаю, должны выполняться два требования:

1. Если в БД есть запись о файле, то он должен существовать.
2. Если выполнить операцию не удалось - надо сообщить об ошибке тому, кто вызывал код.

Оба этих требования у вас выполнены. В этом плане код совершенно корректен.

---

После выполнения основных требований обычно хочется сделать так, чтобы код еще и реже падал с ошибкой. Скажу сразу, ваши предложения - глупые.

Так, `Directory.CreateDirectory` ничего не будет делать если директория уже создана. `File.Move` тоже сам проверит существование исходного и несуществование целевого файлов, дополнительная проверка тут только помешает. Не следует проверять за стандартными функциями то, что они должны проверить сами.

Вместо этого следовало бы подумать о гонке. Гонка возникает всякий раз, когда вы используете `File.Exist` - потому что другая программа (либо второй поток вашей же) может создать либо удалить нужный файл сразу после проверки :)

Вы используете эту проверку в условии цикла `while`, когда ищите свободное имя для файла - но окончательная проверка занятости имени происходит только в методе `File.Move`. Отсюда вывод - надо растягивать цикл таким образом, чтобы в него попал вызов `File.Move`. Проблема тут в том, чтобы отделить ошибку перемещения из-за существования целевого файла от ошибки перемещения по другим причинам:

```
AttachedFile attachedFile;
for(;;)
{
    filePath = generatePathForAttachment();
    dst = Path.Combine(archiveDirectory, filePath);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(dst));

    attachedFile = new AttachedFile
    {
        OriginalTitle = attachment.OriginalTitle,
        Path = filePath,
        Size = attachment.Stream.Length,
        AuthorId = attachment.AuthorId,
        Created = DateTime.Now
    };

    try {
        File.Move(tmpFile, dst);
    } catch {
        if (File.Exists(dst))
          continue;
        else
          throw;
    }
    break;
}
```

Здесь я использую проверку `File.Exists` - но уже после вызова `File.Move`. Если другие программы не будут удалять свежесозданные файлы - то и гонки не будет.

PS какого размера предполагаются файлы? Если небольшого - то проще их хранить в базе.

Comment: размеры файлов сильно разнятся, от нескольких килобайт до нескольких сотен мегабайт, поэтому первоначально я принял решение не хранить файлы в бд